# How to make javascript/jquery code error proof?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, xhtml

If jQuery is included in `<head>` and in `<head>` if we have some another jQuery code and that code has an `id` which is a `id` of an HTML element, so if jQuery library and jquery code in `<head>` is added globally

And if any page doesn't have that html element which is used by jQuery code then browser gives JavaScript error.

Can I make jQuery/JavaScript code like, if jQuery finds an HTML element with id in `<body>` then it should work fine.

If another page doesn't have that HTML element with `id` then I know jQuery will not work.

But what I want:

An error should not be thrown if a page doesn't have an HTML element with the given `id`.

Comment: Do you mean `if ($("#yourID") == undefined)`?

Comment: @Richard E: probably something to that extent, only that selector is never undefined. it is, at the very least, a jquery array of zero elements, so what you want to check is whether length is greater than zero.

Comment: From what I understand (correct me if I’m wrong), you want your code to fail silently if it does not find the “target” on which to do its thing. I think this is bad practice. Check for the target and then run the code. If you have no target, then don’t run. Don’t just keep your fingers crossed…

Comment: @dpb - but when we use cms then usually we use only one header.php file and whatever we include in this it will be applied to all pages.

Comment: Aha... I understand now. You don't know in what kind of page your header will end up. In this case test for the presence of your targets, like in David Hedlund's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of jQuery code works like this already, as it is set-based, and you can do operations on sets of 0 elements. I.e. these will always work, regardless of whether or not the selector matches any elements:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() { ... });
$('#somethingElse').hide();
```

In some cases you really do need a reference to at least one element, however, for the rest of the script to work. In these cases, you have to manually check that the element exists:

```
if($('#myElement').length == 0) return false; // or similar...
```

Comment: @David - can u explain with example?

Comment: `if($('#myElement').length) { ... }` Shorter and does the same thing

Comment: @Jitendra: that was my example! `$('#myElement')` is jQuery code to find all elements with the id "myElement". as it is an array(ish) of elements, you can check its `length` property. if length is 0, it means there was no element with the id "myElement" in the page. Since 0 is *falsy* i.e. resolves to false when used as a boolean, Erik's shorter version is exactly equal.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($('#myElement').length != 0){
  my special js magic thing;
}else{
  return false;
}
```